# Understanding a Math "Meme"?

Tags: calculus, functions

I recently saw this "Math Meme":

[image]

Loosely speaking, I think I understand the humor - even though some functions may appear to look continuous on paper, they are not mathematically continuous as such.

As an example, I think the "Step Function" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) is an example, as I can draw this without lifting my pen/pencil, but is clearly not defined at certain points. **Is this a valid example with regards to this math "meme"? If not, can someone please help me come up with one (e.g. perhaps "Absolute Value Function"?)**

In general:

- Is there any particular relevance of the function that they have drawn in this picture (i.e. function plotted in red)?

Is this an example of a discontinuous function?

- In general, are functions like $$f(x) = x \cdot \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$ considered discontinuous since at $x=0$ this function is "not defined" (i.e. infinity) - but nonetheless, I can still draw it without lifting my pen?

Thanks!

Note: R Simulation

```
# Define function
f <- function(x) x*sin(1/x)

# Plot function
plot(f, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-5, 5), xlab = "x", ylab = "y")

# Add vertical lines at x = 0 and x = (2*k+1)*pi
abline(v = c(0, pi, -pi, 3*pi, -3*pi), lty = 2)
```

[image]

```
Warning message:
In sin(1/x) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: You can't draw a step function without lifting you pen though. The vertical lines that are sometimes drawn are not actually part of the function graph.

Comment: “not defined” is not the same as “infinity”

Comment: Oh, and if you amend $f$ with the definition: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x\cdot\sin(1/x)&x\neq0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$Then it *is* continuous.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies! What about the "absolute value function", i.e. y = |x| ? Is this a valid example?

Comment: The function $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x$ is continuous, but you need a peculiar pen to draw the curve without picking it up.

Comment: @stats_noob $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous everywhere. What you might be thinking of is that it isn't differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: I suspect that the meme is just a comment on how an idea that is simple to explain in terms of actions (without lifting the pen) is more cumbersome to express mathematically.

Comment: "I can draw it without picking up my pen" is a pretty good informal explanation of the concept of continuous functions.

Comment: @stats_noob No, you cannot draw $f(x) = x \cdot \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$ with a pen: it has infinite length when approaching $x=0$ so it would require infinite time; and the oscillations get infinitely close so you would need an infinitely thin pencil line. So the informal definition breaks at least for two reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure if that meme is appropriate for this site (which could explain the downvotes), but a step function is defined everywhere if you define it as $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, like how your Wiki link defines it. What you probably meant to say is that it is discontinuous at some points because the limit from both sides of some "jumps" doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe I will remove the meme and just keep the idea from the meme?

Comment: IMO, that meme is more suited for a math subreddit like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathmemes/) or something like that. I understand it's just a silly picture and I could care less about some screenshot dissing real analysis, but seeing "OTHERWISE IT'S NOT SUFFICIENTLY RIGOROUS!!!!" on this site is off-putting. If you have questions on whether or not it's appropriate to upload math memes, you could ask them on Meta.

Comment: I've written my main answer below, but there is something unrelated that is also important. Take the function $y=1/x$. Ask any student familiar only with the "precalculus definition" and they will tell you that it is "obviously" discontinuous at $x=0$. It takes some *unlearning* on the real analysis course to understand that the question of (dis)continuity at $x=0$ is an invalid question: you cannot even *test* a function for continuity in those points where it is not defined! (In terms of the meme, you need to know the value of $f(C)$ in the first place.)

Comment: @Accelerator +1 for referring the OP to Meta. I also trust the community to eventually decide (by voting) if the question is good. At the moment it stands above zero, more people must've liked it than not.

Comment: Nope, you're expecting far too much.

Comment: Now do $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ (or any other metric spaces, for that matter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit of a philosophical answer, or a rant if you like.

I don't like the joke. The gist of it is that the real analysis is filled with cumbersome and confusing definitions of things that are clear and intuitive and obvious to pre-calculus students. Gets you to think - why study real analysis when all it does is muddle waters and make easy stuff hard? Thus the joke comes across as being derogatory towards the real analysis as a subject. (Well... probably the maker of the joke wasn't very good at real analysis in the first place! Or, at least they felt a bit too strongly for those people who were not.)

In fact, if the definition of continuity needed to involve such complicated entities as "I", " can", "draw", " pen" and "lifting", we would have to define *those* entities first, or give up with using logic in mathematics in the first place! E.g. who says that *you* can draw the same things as *I* can; maybe I don't have a pen (does it work with a pencil?) or I am six months old, or I cannot use a pen (if I am too ill), and nobody *ever* can prove one way or otherwise that $y=\arctan x$ is continuous around $x=10^{100}$. (You can't trick me, this is not $y=\arctan x$, it looks more like $y=\pi/2$ to me!)

So the main point is not in finding example which looks like a function is continuous while rigorously being not, or doesn't look continuous even though it is. The main point is that the pre-calculus definition which includes Earthly creatures (people) and their creations (pens) is not good enough for mathematical use. The "real analysis" definition, warts and all, removes that defficiency at the (small) cost that one needs to study a bit of real analysis to appreciate it.

Comment: @ Stinking Bishop: thank you for your answer! I wonder why so many downvotes lol!

Comment: @stats_noob I hope people are downvoting *the joke* rather than your post.

Comment: @stats_noob In the same spirit as this answer, I’d like to add that the ‘cumbersome’ real analysis definitions and theory of continuity can be conceptually greatly simplified (along with any proofs) with the theory of topology. This meme, leaving humour aside, paints a picture of maths as a bag of ugly language whereas a great effort is made in all areas to simplify the language. It’s also worth noting that there are discontinuous functions that satisfy the intermediate value property, i.e. their graphs ‘could be drawn without lifting a pen’ for a rather ambitious sense of ‘could be drawn’.

Comment: Actually no precalculus professor would ever write "if you can draw it without lifting you pen, it's continuous". That's too gross. So the meme is flawed. That would have worked better if the statement was from a physics course.

Comment: IMHO it is real analysis which is more enjoyable and illuminating. The calculus stuff presented in high school (targeted at students of age 16 years in India) is a just a mix of strange operations whose mechanism seems so different from typical algebraic operations. One is taught the "how" but not the "what" and "why" in a calculus course.