# Applications of Linear Programming to pure mathematics

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, big-list, applications

This semester I'm taking a course in Linear Programming. While the topic is very interesting, all the applications I can find about this topic seem to be outside of mathematics. What are some applications of Linear Programming to pure math? (specially in number theory / algebra / algebraic geometry)

Comment: Why the downvotes? There are many other questions in this site asking about applications of a topic which are well received and this one does not seem to be a duplicate.

Comment: sphere packing (cohn-elkies LP)

Comment: Late comment, but I think the reason for the close votes and downvotes is that this post is an open-ended question. This site is meant for specific questions about how to solve so-and-so math problems. But I've seen opinionated posts like this that accumulated positive feedback like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857983/when-studying-a-book-like-rudin-where-the-problems-are-not-intended-to-be-ful) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601394/understanding-a-math-meme), both of which are against the rules, but some people like me don't care that much.

Comment: It could be turned into an answer, but I don't have the time, so I'll just leave a comment; [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.05495) is a paper using integer programming to disprove a number of conjectures (and improve several lower bounds) in extremal combinatorics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, it should be noted that Linear Programming (LP) **has benefited from** many mathematical tools, for a review, see e.g., [Algebraic and Topological Tools in Linear Optimization](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201907/rnoti-p1023.pdf) and [Integer Programming and Number Theory](https://nyaspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1749-6632.1981.tb51145.x).

Moreover, due to its widespread usage, LP has **become a strong driver** for the study of challenging math problems such as $d$-step conjecture for polyhedrons (see this Acta Mathematica paper: [The d-step conjecture for polyhedra of dimension $d<6$](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-117/issue-none/The-d-step-conjecture-for-polyhedra-of-dimension-d6/10.1007/BF02395040.full)) or the development of branches of mathematics such as [convex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_analysis#:%7E:text=Convex%20analysis%20is%20the%20branch,A%203%2Ddimensional%20convex%20polytope.) and tropical geometry (see Chapter 1.2 in the book [Introduction to Tropical Geometry](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301003344id_/http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/D.Maclagan/papers/TropicalBook28.2.14.pdf) and pages 1031-1032 in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201907/rnoti-p1023.pdf)).

The relationship between LP and mathematics is not one-sided and **LP and its well-known extensions**, such as convex optimization and integer programming, has been applied in different fields of mathematics.

- Convex Optimization, a nice non-linear extension of LP that can be solved efficiently, has found many applications in **geometry** such as projection on a set, distance between sets, Euclidean distance and angle problems, extremal volume ellipsoids, etc. (see chapter 8 of the book [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf))
- Integer programming, a discrete counterpart of LP that can be solved efficiently using LP-based branch-and-bound, has been also applied for analyzing and solving difficult **graph-theoretic** problems (see chapters on applications of the book [Combinatorial Optimization](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-29297-7?page=2#toc)). The [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316519301116) pointed out by @MishaLavrov in a comment is an interesting usage of integer programming to disprove conjectures and improve several lower bounds in **extremal combinatorics**.
- Semidefinite Programming (SDP) is a very recent extension of LP, for which [an efficient algorithm designed by Farid Alizadeh](https://www.informs.org/Recognizing-Excellence/Award-Recipients/Farid-Alizadeh). In SDP, the order $\ge$ is replaced by $\succeq$. A number of recent papers provided direct or computer-assisted proofs based on **Flag Algebras**, allowing one to establish bounds through a double-counting argument by solving SDP models to prove various results in extremal combinatorics (see this [paper](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/26470) and references therein).
- The **major theoretical breakthrough** that **LP models** with rational input data can **be solved in polynomial time** is a key result in **theoretical computer science** (see The New York Times paper [Leonid Khachiyan, 52; Helped to Advance Computer Math](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/05/23/obituaries/world/leonid-khachiyan-52-helped-to-advance-computer-math.html) and chapter 3 of the book [7](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-29297-7?page=2#toc)).
- Another interesting application of LP is in **probability theory** where the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) (used to compare different probability measures) can be obtained from a transportation problem when the sample space is finite (a well-known LP problem taught in undergrad LP courses, can be solved in polynomial time).
- The second application of LP in **probability theory** is to **derive sharp analytical bounds** for the probability of the union of events or other quantity with partial information, see these interesting papers [13](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X04001386), [14](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.2014.0657), [15](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/21M1408294), and references therein.
- LP enables us to obtain a [Nash equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#:%7E:text=and%20wireless%20communications.-,History,produce%20to%20maximize%20its%20profit.) for a two-player [zero-sum game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_game) with finite strategy sets **in polynomial time**, which is of high theoretical importance as still no polynomial algorithm has discovered to find a Nash equilibrium of two-player general-sum game with finite strategy sets. In fact, this brilliant  application of LP in **game theory** warmly opened the door to develop the amazing concept of [duality in optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)) (inspired by John von Neumann's min-max concept) with many theoretical applications in other fields.
- LP bounding has been used in the **sphere packing problem** (what fraction of $\mathbb R^n$ can be covered by congruent balls not intersecting except along their boundaries). Here, I list a number of papers published in $\color{red}{\text{Annals of Mathematics}}$, the most prestigious journal in mathematics, on sphere packing in which **linear programming** has been successfully used:
- [Universal optimality of the $E_8$ and Leech lattices and interpolation formulas](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2022/196-3/p03),
- [The sphere packing problem in dimension 24](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2017/185-3/p08)
- [New upper bounds on sphere packings I](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2003/157-2/p09)

I quote the following statement from the third [paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2003/157-2/p09):

> **Linear programming bounds** (Delsarte, 1972) **are the most powerful
> known technique** for producing upper bounds in **such problems**. In particular, Kabatiansky and Levenshtein (1978) use this technique to prove the best bounds known for sphere packing density in high dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Some applications of duality in linear programming are:

- It provides a unifying framework for a lot of min-max theorem (Kőnig-Egervary theorem, Hall's theorem, Tutte-Berge formula, Menger's theorem, Max-flow min-cut, Dilworth’s theorem, matroid intersection theorem...)
- Is is the basis for a lot of approximation guarantee results, by the use of rounding procedures.
- It can give some theoretical bounds (LP bound and MRRW bound in the theory of codes, LP bounds for sphere packing)